# Group By of Dataframe by Index and value in python

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

This is similar to what i have, except there are many more columns and rows to the dataframe.

```
df =

   1  2  3
A  0  0  1
B  1  0  0
C  0  1  0
D  0  1  0
E  1  0  0
F  0  1  0
G  0  0  1
```

My Desired Output:

```
result =

   1  2  3
0  B  C  A
1  E  D  G
2     F
```

What is best and fastest way i can accomplish this? I cannot possibly go through each row to and iterate through it as the actual dataframe has 1000s of rows and columns.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please explain the behaviour you are showing here and what you tried so far

Comment: what is the pattern?

Comment: @Andreas Basically you can think of 0 as false and 1 as true, and i want to know which columns have what indexes true. I got this data after running PCA/TSE-N.

Comment: @Andreas was trying to replace each '1' value with the index name and then replacing '0' with NaN. then grouping each column with all values other than NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `pd.melt` and `pd.groupby` to achive that:

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'1': {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 1, 'F': 0, 'G': 0},
 '2': {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 1, 'D': 1, 'E': 0, 'F': 1, 'G': 0},
 '3': {'A': 1, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 0, 'F': 0, 'G': 1}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).reset_index()
```

**Code:**

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='index')
df = df[df['value'].eq(1)]
df['row'] = df.groupby(['variable'])['value'].transform('cumsum')
df.pivot(index='row', columns='variable', values='index')
```

**Output:**

```
variable    1  2    3
row                  
1           B  C    A
2           E  D    G
3         NaN  F  NaN
```

Comment: @YashYadati I am glad it was of some use. If you think this answers your question please accept the answer and you can also upvote if you like, this helps future readers to find the right answer faster and also gives me a few points. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

This is a single line answer --
no need to groupby, cumsum, transform, melt, pivot, etc. like in the accepted answer. For the sake of clarity I'll put it into two lines:

```
res = df.mask(df.astype(bool),df.index).replace(0,np.nan)\
      .apply(lambda x: x.dropna().reset_index(drop=True))
```

The first line above creates the `res` dataframe by replacing `1`s with the corresponding index value and replaces `0`s with `NaN`s:

```
     1    2    3
A  NaN  NaN    A
B    B  NaN  NaN
C  NaN    C  NaN
D  NaN    D  NaN
E    E  NaN  NaN
F  NaN    F  NaN
G  NaN  NaN    G
```

The second line drops the `NaN`s in each column, resets each column's index, and combines them back:

```
     1  2    3
0    B  C    A
1    E  D    G
2  NaN  F  NaN
```

The full code below for others to easily replicate:

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

df ="""\
   1  2  3
A  0  0  1
B  1  0  0
C  0  1  0
D  0  1  0
E  1  0  0
F  0  1  0
G  0  0  1
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df),sep='\s+')

res = df.mask(df.astype(bool),df.index).replace(0,np.nan)
res.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().reset_index(drop=True))
     1  2    3
0    B  C    A
1    E  D    G
2  NaN  F  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, this was good too, had tried this but @Andreas answer was what i was looking for.

Comment: I've added one liner to get to the format you request. That line drops NAs and combines the columns back again. I think mine is a more straightforward answer, no need to groupby, cumsum, transform, melt, pivot etc.

Comment: I know this should be an easy fix but I get this when i try it: "TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not DataFrame", you know how to fix this easily?

Comment: @Yash I copied and pasted the above snippet into my notebook and it just worked. It looks like this is related to StringIO (please google the error for the solution). So you can just ignore the first two lines of the code (that creates the df in your example) and just use the last two lines, i.e., the actual solution.